# ggplot: How to label facets when using `facet_zoom()` from `ggforce` packge?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

When using `facet_zoom()` from `{ggforce}` packge, is there a way to label the facets themselves?

For example, I can produce the following plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_zoom(x = Species == 'versicolor') +
  labs(caption = "Figure 1. a) entire data range; b) zoom in on versicolor") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

But how can I actually label the facets? I want to achieve something like:

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

A ***manual*** solution can be based on `draw_label()` from `{cowplot}` package:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(cowplot)

p <- 
  ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_zoom(x = Species == 'versicolor') +
  labs(caption = "Figure 1. a) entire data range; b) zoom in on versicolor") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0))

ggdraw(p) +
  draw_label("a)", color = "black", size = 15, x = 0.09, y = 0.95) +
  draw_label("b)", color = "black", size = 15, x = 0.09, y = 0.6)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

However, this is far from optimal because the position of the labels is absolute, meaning that resizing the plot in RStudio also changes the position. An optimal solution would *anchor* the labels to a certain position in respect to the facet, such as: `"upper-left"`, thus immune to resizing.